# code to exclude weekends an bank holidays

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write the code to get the "date" excluding weekends and bank holidays( which means when I enter the date and number of days, it should exclude weekends and bank holidays, like when I give 03-24-2017 and 3 days, it should give 03-31-2017 assuming 29th is a holiday). I got the code for whole thing, but it is taking todays date, but I wish to enter the date manually, I tried with document.getElementById("today").value; but its not giving any output.Thanks in advance.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title> Add Days and Holidays </title>

</head>
<body>

<pre id="fourWeeks"></pre>
Add <input id="nDaysToAdd" value="0"> days<p>
<button onclick="calcBusinessDay()"> Calculate 

</button>
<div id="debug"</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var today = new Date();  
var holidays = [
   [2017,2,10], 

before holiday
   [2017,7,4], 
];

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) { return new 

Date(this.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000); }

Date.prototype.addBusAndHoliDays = function (days) {
  var cDate = this; 
  var holiday = new Date();
  var c='', h='';
  for (var i=1; i<=days ; i++){
    cDate.setDate(cDate.getDate() + 1);
    if (cDate.getDay() == 6 || cDate.getDay() == 0) { 

days++; }
 else {
   for (j=0; j<holidays.length; j++) {
     holiday = new 

Date(holidays[j][0],(holidays[j][1]-1),holidays[j][2]);
  c = cDate.toDateString();  h = 

holiday.toDateString();
     if (c == h) { days++; }
   }
 }
  } return cDate;
}

  
Date.prototype.DayList = function (daysToShow) {
  var td = this;
  if (daysToShow == undefined) { daysToShow = 31; }

  var str = '';
  for (var i=0; i<daysToShow; i++) {
    newday = new 

Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth(),(td.getDate()+i));
    str += newday.toDateString()+'\t  =>\t'+i+' actual days 

ahead<br>';
  } return str;
}

function calcBusinessDay() {  

functions
  var today = new Date();
  var N = 

parseInt(document.getElementById('nDaysToAdd').valu

e) || 0;
  
  var wd = today.addDays(N);
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML 
    = '<p>'+N+' week days from today 

('+today.toDateString() +') will be on: 

'+wd.toDateString();

  var bd = today.addBusAndHoliDays(N);
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML += 

'<p>'+N+' business days will be on: '+bd.toDateString();

  str += '<p>'+newDay.DayList(14);
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML += 

'<p>'+str;
  

  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and where is the code? What have you tried so far on this context ?

Answer (score 0):

With `document.getElementById("today").value` you get the value of an INPUT html element, and you don't have any input with todays value.

Here's an snippet getting todays date (**Warning**: the date is formatted d/m/y)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat/master/Date.format.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  Today: <input id="today" type="text">
  <br>
  <button onclick="calculate()" >Calculate something</button>
  
  <div id="results" style="margin-top: 20px; border: red;"></div>
  
  <script>
    document.getElementById("today").value = new Date().format('d/m/Y');
    
    function calculate() {
        var splitted = document.getElementById("today").value.split("/");
        var today = new Date(splitted[2], splitted[1] - 1, splitted[0]);      
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;
      
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```